# Should i lock a list before performing a parallel loop on it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method, that pulls a list of objects, then uses a Parallel.ForEach loop to iterate over the list and perform some simple operations. there is also 1 database call inside the Parallel.ForEach, See code sample.

i am wondering if the lock is needed, or when a lock would be needed.

this project is a ASP.Net MVC project, this method is called when a button is clicked in the interface.

List toReturn = new List();

```
var allGr = Task.Run(() => Tr.GaGr(AuthManager.DepartmentId, 1));
allGr .Wait();

lock (allGr)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(allGr .Result.ToList(), myGri =>
    {
        Groups myGr = new Groups();
        var getGrp = Task.Run(() => myGr.GGID(myGri.GID.Value));
        getGrp.Wait();

        toReturn.Add(myGr);
    });
}
```

Comment: Why would you wrap synchronous code in a Task and then wait for it to complete in a blocking manner? What are you trying to accomplish? And what does `GGID` do?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: Also, for concurrent access to collections, a [concurrent collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/) can be useful.

Comment: Are you using a local variable for your lock?  That doesn't do very much.  You don't "lock a list", you use an object to lock sections of code.  Generally, code with a lock includes a member field that looks like `private object myLock = new object()` (or, maybe a collection of locks).

Comment: @PeterBons GGID is a method that retrieves a group information from the database.

Comment: @PeterBons i am attempting to refactor this code, it was written by another developer, and i am not very experienced with locks at all.

also, the method this code is located in, is not async, i believe that is why the Task.Run's were added, although i fail to see the benefit personally.

Comment: The Parallel.ForEach will safely marshal the elements for you, so as long as you don't try and mutate the list itself (add/remove/etc) from within the loop (which isn't permitted in a regular foreach either) and either your element itself is threadsafe or is guaranteed to only exist once (the same object, not just an equal object) in your list, you don't need to lock it.